# Calculate a SUM of the SUM of columns in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sum, aggregate

I'd like to get another column with percentages of chars used by any user.

To do that I need to take the total chars got for all posts of a user in his/her posts.title and posts.body sum them and after sum all chars of all users.

I get this table:

```
'name', 'chars_title', 'chars_body', 'chars_total'
'user1', '7', '6', '13'
'user2', '27', '23', '50'
'user3', '6', '5', '11'
```

With this query:

```
SELECT users.name,
   sum(length(posts.title)) as chars_title, 
   sum(length(posts.body)) chars_body, 
   sum(length(posts.title)+length(posts.body)) chars_total
FROM test.posts posts
JOIN test.users users
ON posts.user_id=users.id
GROUP BY users.name
ORDER BY chars_total DESC;
```

Can I get percentages of char used by user by with chars_total and a function that gives me a total of char_total?

For instance a function that sums 13+50+11 on an already aggregated columns?

Comment: Thinking on maybe a solution is only a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can `CROSS JOIN` this query:

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(title) + LENGTH(body)) total FROM posts
```

which returns the total chars of all users in the table:

```
SELECT u.name,
       p.chars_title,
       p.chars_body,
       p.chars_title + p.chars_body chars_total,       
       100.0 * (p.chars_title + p.chars_body) / c.total percentage
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT user_id,
         SUM(LENGTH(title)) chars_title, 
         SUM(LENGTH(body)) chars_body
  FROM posts 
  GROUP BY user_id
) p ON p.user_id = u.id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(LENGTH(title) + LENGTH(body)) total FROM posts) c
```

Note that maybe you should use [`CHAR_LENGTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) instead of [`LENGTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length).

Comment: I have an error in this way, I need to check it better.

Comment: @Salvio I already corrected typos. the query is syntactically correct: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tBHJs6dhp6YFCH4R9FNgov/0

Comment: I found another solution I posted: creating a temporary table and put the total in a varible to use it in a final query. What do you think it's less expensive? @forpas?

Comment: That comment is an answer to a (now deleted) comment by another user, so I must delete it too.

Comment: @Salvio there is no need of a temporary table. All it takes is a (not that complicated) query.

Comment: Whiy if do I turn CROSS JOIN into a INNER one everything works?

Comment: You will have to test the performance. MySql allows INNER join without an ON clause (which is actually a CROSS JOIN).

Comment: Anyway I thought about the two way to perfom this. If I have 100000 users with the cross join I'll have 100000 field in the intermediary table and during the first join 100000 float fields that I think it's very expensive ram usage. 

Putting a value in a variable using a temporary table that can be updated by a trigger on the users and posts tables should be a better solution to less intensive ram usage.

Any idea about?

Comment: A temporary table and triggers for insert/update/delete? I don't know. You have to try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then you may use `SUM()` as an analytic function here:

```
SELECT
    u.name,
    SUM(LENGTH(p.title)) chars_title, 
    SUM(LENGTH(p.body)) chars_body, 
    SUM(LENGTH(p.title) + LENGTH(p.body)) chars_total,
    100.0 * SUM(LENGTH(p.title) + LENGTH(p.body)) /
        SUM(SUM(LENGTH(p.title) + LENGTH(p.body))) OVER ()
        AS chars_total_pct
FROM test.posts p
INNER JOIN test.users u
    ON p.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY
    u.name
ORDER BY
    chars_total DESC;
```

Comment: And with MYSQL 5.7+?

Comment: ...can you upgrade? `:-)`

Comment: Unluckly I can't, it's a legacy project.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I've solved in this way:

1)I've create a temporary table to put the first query result:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS total SELECT users.name,
   sum(length(posts.title)) as chars_title, 
   sum(length(posts.body)) chars_body, 
   sum(length(posts.title)+length(posts.body)) chars_total
FROM test.posts posts
JOIN test.users users
ON posts.user_id=users.id
GROUP BY users.name
ORDER BY chars_total DESC;
```

2)Calculated the sum on the temprary table and put it in a variable:

```
SELECT sum(chars_total) FROM total INTO @total_chars;
```

3)Make a query on temporary table using variable:

```
SELECT name, 
       chars_title, 
       chars_body, 
       chars_total, 
       ROUND(chars_total*100/@total_chars, 0) as percentage
FROM total;
```

I think it's bit dirty solution but for now it's ok.